# Horizontal polygon sides subdivision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, interpolation, polygon, division

Let's say there is some arbitrary polygons having adjusting common sides.

[image]

The task is to subdivide horizontal sides, where points Xs don't much with each other, by using simple algorithm method `simpleInterpolation(curve_, n_)`, in a way so the result would be:

[image]

The attached snippet need to be updated at polygons.forEach(...).

```
polygons.forEach((polygon_, i_) => {

    let segments = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < polygon_.length; i++){

        let p1 = polygon_[i];
        let p2 = polygon_[(i + 1) % polygon_.length];
        let p3 = polygon_[(i + 2) % polygon_.length];

        if(p1.x !== p2.x && p3.x !== p2.x){


            if(segments.length === 0) {

                segments.push({ indices: [i, (i + 1) % polygon_.length, (i + 2) % polygon_.length], points: [p1, p2, p3]});

            }
            else{

                let lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];

                if((i + 1) % polygon_.length !== lastSegment.indices[lastSegment.indices.length - 1]){

                    segments.push({ indices: [i, (i + 1) % polygon_.length, (i + 2) % polygon_.length], points: [p1, p2, p3] });

                }
                else { 
                    
                    lastSegment.indices.push((i + 2) % polygon_.length);
                    lastSegment.points.push(p3);
                
                }

            }

        }

    }

    segments.forEach((segment_) => { segment_.points = simpleInterpolation(segment_.points, 4); })

    console.log(segments);

})
```

There is already part which finds whose segments to be updated, I couldn't figure out how to replace old points with a new ones generated by `simpleInterpolation(curve_, n_)`. These segments could have start index greater than end, since the code checks last points with two first ones, so it makes updating tricky and segments could be shuffles, so starting indices couldn't fit simple increment.

```js
const data = {

    up: [

        { x: 200, y: 140 },
        { x: 300, y: 100 },
        { x: 500, y: 120 },
        { x: 600, y: 140 },
        { x: 600, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 400, y: 532.2 },
        { x: 200, y: 352.2 }

    ],

    down: [

        { x: 200, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 400, y: 532.2 },
        { x: 600, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 600, y: 660 },
        { x: 200, y: 660 }

    ],

    debug0: [

        { x: 200, y: 140 },
        { x: 400, y: 100 },
        { x: 600, y: 140 },

    ],

    debug1: [

        { x: 200, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 400, y: 532.2 },
        { x: 600, y: 352.2 }

    ],

    debugUp: [

        { x: 200, y: 140},
        { x: 212.5, y: 137.5},
        { x: 275, y: 130},
        { x: 400, y: 125},
        { x: 525, y: 130},
        { x: 587.5, y: 137.5},
        { x: 600, y: 140},
        { x: 600, y: 352.2},
        { x: 587.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 525, y: 397.2},
        { x: 400, y: 419.70},
        { x: 275, y: 397.2},
        { x: 212.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 200, y: 352.2}

    ],

    debugDown: [

        { x: 200, y: 352.2},
        { x: 212.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 275, y: 397.2},
        { x: 400, y: 419.70},
        { x: 525, y: 397.2},
        { x: 587.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 600, y: 352.2},
        { x: 600, y: 660 },
        { x: 200, y: 660 }

    ]

};

let svg, curve0, curve1, EPS = 1E-5;

svg = d3.select("#scene");

let polygons = [data.up, data.down];

polygons.forEach((polygon_, i_) => {

    let segments = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < polygon_.length; i++){

        let p1 = polygon_[i];
        let p2 = polygon_[(i + 1) % polygon_.length];
        let p3 = polygon_[(i + 2) % polygon_.length];

        if(p1.x !== p2.x && p3.x !== p2.x){


            if(segments.length === 0) {

                segments.push({ indices: [i, (i + 1) % polygon_.length, (i + 2) % polygon_.length], points: [p1, p2, p3]});

            }
            else{

                let lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];

                if((i + 1) % polygon_.length !== lastSegment.indices[lastSegment.indices.length - 1]){

                    segments.push({ indices: [i, (i + 1) % polygon_.length, (i + 2) % polygon_.length], points: [p1, p2, p3] });

                }
                else { 
                    
                    lastSegment.indices.push((i + 2) % polygon_.length);
                    lastSegment.points.push(p3);
                
                }

            }

        }

    }

    segments.forEach((segment_) => { segment_.points = simpleInterpolation(segment_.points, 4); })

    console.log(segments);

})

let left = svg.append("g");

left.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.up, true))
.attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
.attr("fill", "#808080");

left.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.down, true))
.attr("stroke", "#00FFFF")
.attr("fill", "#404040");

debugCurve0 = simpleInterpolation(data.debug0, 4);

left. append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(debugCurve0, false))
.attr("stroke", "#FF0000")
.attr("fill", "none");

let dots0 = left.selectAll(".debug0")
.data(debugCurve0)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "debug0")
.attr("cx", d_ => d_.x)
.attr("cy", d_ => d_.y)
.attr("r", 4)
.attr("fill", "#FF0000");

debugCurve1 = simpleInterpolation(data.debug1, 4);

left.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(debugCurve1, false))
.attr("stroke", "#FF0000")
.attr("fill", "none");

let dots1 = left.selectAll(".debug1")
.data(debugCurve1)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "debug0")
.attr("cx", d_ => d_.x)
.attr("cy", d_ => d_.y)
.attr("r", 4)
.attr("fill", "#FF0000");

let right = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(800, 0)");

right.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.debugUp, true))
.attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
.attr("fill", "#808080");

right.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.debugDown, true))
.attr("stroke", "#00FFFF")
.attr("fill", "#404040");


function simpleInterpolation(curve_, n_){

    let out, input = [...curve_];

    for(let i = 0; i < n_; i++){

        out = [input[0]];

        for(let j = 0; j < input.length - 1; j++){

            let p0 = input[j];
            let p1 = input[j + 1];

            let m01 = median(p0, p1, 0.5);

            out.push(m01);

        }

        out.push(input[input.length - 1]);
        input = out;

    }

    return out;

}

function median(p0_, p1_, t_){ return {x: p0_.x + (p1_.x - p0_.x) * t_, y: p0_.y + (p1_.y - p0_.y) * t_}; }

function generatePathFromPoints(points_, closed_){

    let d = `M${points_[0].x} ${points_[0].y}`;

    for(let i = 1; i < points_.length; i++) { d += `L${points_[i].x} ${points_[i].y}`; }

    if(closed_) { d += "Z"; }

    return d;

}
```

```css
body: { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="scene" viewBox="0 0 1600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very rough solution. Right shapes is just for reference.

```js
const data = {

    up: [

        { x: 200, y: 140 },
        { x: 400, y: 100},
        { x: 600, y: 140 },
        { x: 600, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 400, y: 532.2 },
        { x: 200, y: 352.2 }

    ],

    down: [

        { x: 200, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 400, y: 532.2 },
        { x: 600, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 600, y: 660 },
        { x: 200, y: 660 }

    ],

    debug0: [

        { x: 200, y: 140 },
        { x: 400, y: 100 },
        { x: 600, y: 140 },

    ],

    debug1: [

        { x: 200, y: 352.2 },
        { x: 400, y: 532.2 },
        { x: 600, y: 352.2 }

    ],

    debugUp: [

        { x: 200, y: 140},
        { x: 212.5, y: 137.5},
        { x: 275, y: 130},
        { x: 400, y: 125},
        { x: 525, y: 130},
        { x: 587.5, y: 137.5},
        { x: 600, y: 140},
        { x: 600, y: 352.2},
        { x: 587.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 525, y: 397.2},
        { x: 400, y: 419.70},
        { x: 275, y: 397.2},
        { x: 212.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 200, y: 352.2}

    ],

    debugDown: [

        { x: 200, y: 352.2},
        { x: 212.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 275, y: 397.2},
        { x: 400, y: 419.70},
        { x: 525, y: 397.2},
        { x: 587.5, y: 363.45},
        { x: 600, y: 352.2},
        { x: 600, y: 660 },
        { x: 200, y: 660 }

    ]

};

let svg, curve0, curve1, EPS = 1E-5;

svg = d3.select("#scene");

data.up = subdividePolygon(data.up, 4);
data.down = subdividePolygon(data.down, 4);

let left = svg.append("g");

left.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.up, true))
.attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
.attr("fill", "#808080");

left.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.down, true))
.attr("stroke", "#00FFFF")
.attr("fill", "#404040");

debugCurve0 = simpleInterpolation(data.debug0, 4);

left. append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(debugCurve0, false))
.attr("stroke", "#FF0000")
.attr("fill", "none");

let dots0 = left.selectAll(".debug0")
.data(debugCurve0)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "debug0")
.attr("cx", d_ => d_.x)
.attr("cy", d_ => d_.y)
.attr("r", 4)
.attr("fill", "#FF0000");

debugCurve1 = simpleInterpolation(data.debug1, 4);

left.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(debugCurve1, false))
.attr("stroke", "#FF0000")
.attr("fill", "none");

let dots1 = left.selectAll(".debug1")
.data(debugCurve1)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "debug0")
.attr("cx", d_ => d_.x)
.attr("cy", d_ => d_.y)
.attr("r", 4)
.attr("fill", "#FF0000");

let right = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(800, 0)");

right.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.debugUp, true))
.attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
.attr("fill", "#808080");

right.append("path")
.attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.debugDown, true))
.attr("stroke", "#00FFFF")
.attr("fill", "#404040");

function subdividePolygon(polygon_, n_) {

    let segments = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < polygon_.length; i++){

    let p1 = polygon_[i];
    let p2 = polygon_[(i + 1) % polygon_.length];
    let p3 = polygon_[(i + 2) % polygon_.length];

    if(p1.x !== p2.x && p3.x !== p2.x){


        if(segments.length === 0) {

            segments.push({ indices: [i, (i + 1) % polygon_.length, (i + 2) % polygon_.length], points: [p1, p2, p3]});

        }
        else{

            let lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];

            if((i + 1) % polygon_.length !== lastSegment.indices[lastSegment.indices.length - 1]){

                segments.push({ indices: [i, (i + 1) % polygon_.length, (i + 2) % polygon_.length], points: [p1, p2, p3] });

            }
            else { 
                
                lastSegment.indices.push((i + 2) % polygon_.length);
                lastSegment.points.push(p3);
            
            }

        }

    }

    }

    segments.forEach((segment_) => { segment_.points = simpleInterpolation(segment_.points, n_); })

    let newpoints = Array.from({length: polygon_.length}, (d_, i_)=> i_);

    segments.forEach((segment_) => {

    newpoints.splice(newpoints.indexOf(segment_.indices[0]), segment_.indices.length, ...segment_.points);

    })

    for(let i = 0; i < newpoints.length; i++){

    if(typeof newpoints[i] == 'number') { newpoints[i] = polygon_[newpoints[i]]; }

    }

    return newpoints;

}

function simpleInterpolation(curve_, n_){

    let out, input = [...curve_];

    for(let i = 0; i < n_; i++){

        out = [input[0]];

        for(let j = 0; j < input.length - 1; j++){

            let p0 = input[j];
            let p1 = input[j + 1];

            let m01 = median(p0, p1, 0.5);

            out.push(m01);

        }

        out.push(input[input.length - 1]);
        input = out;

    }

    return out;

}

function median(p0_, p1_, t_){ return {x: p0_.x + (p1_.x - p0_.x) * t_, y: p0_.y + (p1_.y - p0_.y) * t_}; }

function generatePathFromPoints(points_, closed_){

    let d = `M${points_[0].x} ${points_[0].y}`;

    for(let i = 1; i < points_.length; i++) { d += `L${points_[i].x} ${points_[i].y}`; }

    if(closed_) { d += "Z"; }

    return d;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="scene" viewBox="0 0 1600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood exactly your problem, but if you want to interpolate all sequences of segments that don't contain a vertical segment, then the solution seems rather simpler:

```js
    const NMultiplyByInterpolation = 5;
    // multiply the number of points in the interpolated curve by a factor of NMultiplyByInterpolation
    // e.g., for 3 points generate 3*NMultiplyByInterpolation
    // the larger NMultiplyByInterpolation, the smoother the interpolation

    const data = {
        up: [
            {x: 200, y: 140},
            {x: 300, y: 100},
            {x: 500, y: 120},
            {x: 600, y: 140},
            {x: 600, y: 352.2},
            {x: 400, y: 532.2},
            {x: 200, y: 352.2}
        ],

        down: [
            {x: 200, y: 352.2},
            {x: 400, y: 532.2},
            {x: 600, y: 352.2},
            {x: 600, y: 660},
            {x: 200, y: 660}
        ]
    };

    const polygonNames = Object.keys(data); // ["up", "down"]
    const interpolatedData = Object.fromEntries(polygonNames.map(key=>[key, []])); // {up: [], down: []}

    polygonNames.forEach((key_) => {
        const polygon_ = data[key_]; // original polygon
        const newPolygon = interpolatedData[key_]; // new polygon we build

        let p2 = polygon_[0];
        let segments = [p2];
        for(let i = 0; i < polygon_.length; i++){
            let p1 = p2;
            p2 = polygon_[(i + 1) % polygon_.length];
            if(p1.x !== p2.x){
                segments.push(p2);
            }
            else{
                if(segments.length > 1){
                    newPolygon.push(...simpleInterpolation(segments, segments.length*NMultiplyByInterpolation));
                }
                else if(segments.length === 1){
                    newPolygon.push(segments[0]);
                }
                if(newPolygon.length === 0){
                    newPolygon.push(p1);
                }
                newPolygon.push(p1,p2);
                segments = [p2];
            }
        }
        if(segments.length > 1){
            newPolygon.push(...simpleInterpolation(segments_.points, segments_.points.length*NMultiplyByInterpolation));
        }
        else if(segments.length === 1){
            newPolygon.push(segments[0]);
        }
    });


    let svg = d3.select("#scene");

    let left = svg.append("g");

    left.append("path")
        .attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.up, true))
        .attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
        .attr("fill", "#808080");

    left.append("path")
        .attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(data.down, true))
        .attr("stroke", "#00FFFF")
        .attr("fill", "#404040");


    let right = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(800, 0)");

    right.append("path")
        .attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(interpolatedData.up, true))
        .attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
        .attr("fill", "#808080");

    right.append("path")
        .attr("d", generatePathFromPoints(interpolatedData.down, true))
        .attr("stroke", "#00FFFF")
        .attr("fill", "#404040");


    function simpleInterpolation(curve_, n_){
        let out, input = [...curve_];
        for(let i = 0; i < n_; i++){
            out = [input[0]];
            for(let j = 0; j < input.length - 1; j++){
                let p0 = input[j];
                let p1 = input[j + 1];
                let m01 = median(p0, p1, 0.5);
                out.push(m01);
            }
            out.push(input[input.length - 1]);
            input = out;
        }
        return out;
    }

    function median(p0_, p1_, t_){ return {x: p0_.x + (p1_.x - p0_.x) * t_, y: p0_.y + (p1_.y - p0_.y) * t_}; }

    function generatePathFromPoints(points_, closed_){
        let d = `M${points_[0].x} ${points_[0].y}`;
        for(let i = 1; i < points_.length; i++){
            d += `L${points_[i].x} ${points_[i].y}`;
        }
        if(closed_){
            d += "Z";
        }
        return d;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="scene" viewBox="0 0 1600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
```